# Simple C++ compilation process

Tags: c++, compilation

it has been a few years since using C++, and I am having a very simple problem that I can't seem to figure out. Here is my super simple hello world program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have already installed all the compilers, however whenever I compile, I get the strangest errors:

```
./untitled: line 3: using: command not found
./untitled: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./untitled: line 5: `int main()'
```

These all seem like very standard lines in C++ code, yet they won't work for some reason.  Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: And how exactly do you compile? (what is the exact command you're running?)

Comment: The code itself is perfectly valid, those compiler errors sound like something's wrong with the compiling process. Are you sure you're saving the file with the .cpp extension?

Comment: It looks like you're compiling C, not C++. Check your compiler doc for this.

Answer (score 5):

Your source code appears to be saved in a file called `untitled`. Save it as a named file ending in `.cpp` and the compiler should then properly treat it as a C++ source file (instead of C - it looks like without further hints, your compiler defaults to C).

Comment: You're right, I made a rookie mistake and forgot to save the output file as .cpp. It works perfectly now, thank you!